# What c++ ( generic (c/c++) vs (generic c)/c++ )

Tags: c++, c

I am a programming student and have occasionally encountered references to: Generic C, does this mean just plain classic C?

"generic c/c++ implementations for structures in any serious piece of software"

It typically appears in contexts such as this; I am pretty sure that I have simply been misreading such references as (generic c)/c++ rather than: generic (c/c++). it looks like it is probably referring to a set of libraries. Thanks for all your replies.

Comment: It's unlikely that any of those terms are real, technical terms. It sounds like someone was speaking colloquially, maybe over a beer, and maybe even someone who would say "C/C++" without blushing. Do you have a complete sample sentence?

Comment: It sounds like you are asking what a generic data type is, but at the same time you do not show any research effort.

Comment: Probably the term "generic" in your sentence refers to "implementations", not "c/c++".

Comment: There is no such thing as generic C, so I think you've just misread "generic (c/c++) implementations" as referring to "generic C"

Answer (score 3):

## There is no such language as “C/C++”.

Which in general (pun intended) means that the sources using it aren't really credible. And that still applies to "generic C".

Comment: True. And worth noting. But it doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: This answer is true, but not really useful here, because it is meaningful to refer to "C/C++ implementations of data structures" if it doesn't mean "implementations in the C/C++ language"

Answer (score 2):

> "generic c/c++ implementations for structures in any serious piece of software"

:)

This is not about Generic C or Generic C++ but about generic implementations for structures in code that can be compiled in C or C++.

It's an ambiguity of the English language.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there's a well established interpretation of the term "generic C". It certainly isn't a formal or technical term, so you'll just have to try to infer the author's intended meaning from the context.

My best guess is that it probably usually means non-platform-specific C, in which case it applies to C++ as much as to C.

Answer (score 0):

Example of generic appoach is

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
struct array {
    T e[N];
    T* begin() {return e;}
    T* end() {return e+N;}
    size_t size() const {return N;}
};
...
array<int, 2> a1 = {1, 2};
array<double, 2> a2 = {10.0, 2.0};
```

As you can see that the array definition is independent of type and size. Such structers/functions are named "generic". So any techniques using such approach can be named "generic".

Comment: This is true, but not relevant to the question

Comment: I think it is exactly relevant, because it shows what "generic" means.

Comment: Given the context of the question, do you think "generic C implementations" refers to C++ templates? I don't.

Comment: C++ templates are historical improvement of C macros. why not?